# How to set type in immer `produce` function with complex type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immer.js

I'm using immer `produce` to set an author which is a part of a complex object, `Book`. `setUnsavedBook` is a react hook set function:

```
onChange={(event) => setUnsavedBook(produce<any>((draft: any) => {draft.preface.author = event.target.value}))}
```

However when I don't have the type `any` in these places I get a typescript error complaining that looks something like this:

```
Argument of type '(base: unknown, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Book'
```

I've tried using the recommendations from the immer docs but something like this which should work

```
onChange={(event) => setUnsavedBook(produce<Book>((draft: Draft<Book>) => {draft.preface.author = event.target.value}))}
```

does not work. I suspect I'm misunderstanding the way that I can assign types in typescript because the error suggests that I'm trying to assign a function to `setUnsavedBook` which expects type `Book` but that is incorrect as I am trying to assign the results of the function not the function itself.

What is wrong with what I wrote?

Comment: You should add a proper type to useState hook and produce draft will automatically infer the type. `const [unsavedBooks, setUnsavedBooks] = useState<{ preface: { author: string } }>({})`. Just use `setUnsavedBook((produce((draft)=> {draft.preface.author = event.target.value} )))` without adding explict type to produce and draft

Comment: Unfortunately I already have the useState hook defined with a type, currently it's either `Book` or `undefined`.

Comment: then `draft` will be undefined and when you try to set value, there will be a typescript error. You can set value like this: `if (draft === undefined) draft = { preface: { author: 'John Doe' } };`